# Change didSelectRowAtIndexPath func IndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have native ads in my tableview and they are displayed using this indexpath:

```
indexPath.row - Int(indexPath.row/adRowStep)
```

How can I change the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function to use the above indexPath?

EDIT

This is the code from the cellForRowAtIndexPath func

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NearMeCell


let venue = venues[indexPath.row - Int(indexPath.row/adRowStep)]

let venueTittle = (venue["Name"] as! String)

 cell.venueName.text = venueTitle

 return cell
  }
```

This is the code for the native ads:

```
func configureAdManagerAndLoadAds() {
        if adsManager == nil {
            adsManager = FBNativeAdsManager(placementID: "adID", forNumAdsRequested: 2)
            FBAdSettings.addTestDevice("clientID")
            adsManager.delegate = self
            adsManager.loadAds()

        }
    }
```

Comment: What about using the same code?

Comment: The line of code you posted doesn't display anything, much less "native ads". We need more information.

Comment: @alexburtnik How would I change the didSelectRowAtIndexPath func to accommodate the different index path because from what I can tell it is using the standard indexPath.row

Comment: @DanielT. What I mean by Native ads is I am using the facebook ads SDK which is inputting an add every 3rd row. This displays using this code: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NearMeCell
        let venue = venues[indexPath.row - Int(indexPath.row/adRowStep)] ...` This works find for displaying the tableView but doesn't correlate when you click on one of the cells to go to a detailview

Comment: @OllieG It will help if you edit your question so the code in the comment is in the question itself. That way it can be formatted properly... and put in the complete code. That snippet doesn't display native ads either.

Comment: @DanielT. Sorry just did the edit. Thanks

Comment: @OllieG You started your question with this code `indexPath.row - Int(indexPath.row/adRowStep)` but your cellForRowAtIndexPath method doesn't use that code, nor does anything else. It will help if you explain, in the question, what it is you are trying to do, the code you are using to do it, and what isn't working about that code. We want to see you succeed, but we need enough information or we can't help.

Comment: @DanielT. Sorry for the misunderstanding I'm new here. I believe I have used the code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath here `let venue = venues[indexPath.row - Int(indexPath.row/adRowStep)]`. This displays the tableview correctly with the ads showing with adRowStep = 3, meaning they show every third row. However when I click on a cell below the first ad and go to the detail view it is actually showing the information that belongs to the cell below. I think that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't realising the ads are present i.e. showing the wrong info. How would I code this to allow for the ads?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand how the ads are being displayed, but based on the information you have given, I expect you need this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
let venue = venues[indexPath.row + Int(indexPath.row/adRowStep)]
```